# Checking if the difference between consecutive elements is the same

Tags: list, prolog

I am new to using arithmetic in Prolog.

I’ve done a few small programs, but mostly involving logic. I am trying to implement a function that will return `true` or `false` if the difference between every consecutive pair of elements is the same or not.

My input would look like this:  `sameSeqDiffs([3, 5, 7, 9], 2)`
I feel like I need to split the first two elements from the list, find their difference, and add the result to a new list. Once all the elements have been processed, check if the elements of the new list are all the same.

I’ve been taught some Prolog with building relationships and querying those, but this doesn’t seem to fit in with Prolog.

Update1: This is what I've come up with so far. I am brand new to this syntax and am still getting an error on my code, but I hope it conveys the general idea of what I'm trying to do.

```
diff([X,Y|Rest], Result):-
    diff([Y,Z|Rest], Result2):-
       Result2 = Result,
       Z - Y = Result.
```

Update2: I know I still have much to do on this code, but here is where I will remain until this weekend, I have some other stuff to do. I think I understand the logic of it a bit more, and I think I need to figure out how to run the last line of the function only if there is at least two more things in the rest of the list to process.

```
diff([X,Y|Rest], Result):-
    number(Y),
    Y-X=Result,
    diff([Rest], Result).
```

Update3: I believe I have the function the way I want it to. The only quirk I noticed is that when I run and input like: `sameSeqDiffs([3,5,7],2).`I get true returned immediately followed by a false. Is this the correct operation or am I still missing something?

```
sameSeqDiffs([X,Y], Result):-
    A is Y - X,
    A = Result.

sameSeqDiffs([X,Y,Z|T], Result):-
    sameSeqDiffs([Y,Z|T], Result).
```

Update 4: I posted a new question about this....here is the link: [Output seems to only test the very last in the list for difference function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52577909/output-seems-to-only-test-the-very-last-in-the-list-for-difference-function)

Comment: Hint: how would you validate this for a list with exactly *two* elements?

Comment: How would you do this for a list that contains more than two elements, in terms of itself?

Comment: can you share your attempt?

Comment: I just edited my question to show my code. Thank you!

Comment: Well a clause that contains another clause in the body does not makes much sense, typically a Prolog predicate is a fact (like `foo(X, Y).`), or a clause (like `foo(X, Y) :- bar(Y), qux(X)`), but not an arrow (`:-`) in the body of a clause.

Comment: See first section of https://www.cis.upenn.edu/~matuszek/Concise%20Guides/Concise%20Prolog.html

Comment: Thank you very much! I come from a background in more C and Java, and got thrown into this problem, which seems to have a steep learning curve. I know I have a lot of work ahead of me.

Comment: Note that `=/2` is not an arithmetic equality check, nor is it an assignment operator. It is a *term unification* operator. So `Y-X=Result` does not evaluate `Y-X` but rather unifies the term `'-'(Y,X)` with `Result`.

Comment: your update3 code is incorrect. please post a new question about it, and include full code and test data. btw you can test it easily, try `[1,2,3,5]` and see what happens.

Comment: I didn't notice that when I was testing at first. I will be sure to post a new question for it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Prolog's syntax

The syntax is a bit off: normally a clause has a head like `foo(X, Y, Z)`, then an arrow (`:-`), followed by a body. That body normally does not contain any arrows `:-`. So the second arrow `:-` makes not much sense.

## Predicates and unification

Secondly in Prolog predicates have no *input* or *output*, a predicate is `true` or `false` (well it can also error, or got stuck into an infinite loop, but that is typically behavior we want to avoid). It communicates answers by *unifying* variables. For example a call `sameSeqDiffs([3, 5, 7, 9], X)`. can succeed by unifying `X` with `2`, and then the predicate - given it is implemented correctly - will return `true.`.

## *Inductive* definitions

In order to design a predicate, on typically first aims to come up with an *inductive definition*: a definition that consists out of one or more base cases, and one or more "recursive" cases (where the predicate is defined by parts of itself).

For example here we can say:

> *(base case)* For a list of exactly two elements `[X, Y]`, the predicate `sameSeqDiffs([X, Y], D)` holds, given `D` is the difference between `Y` and `X`.

In Prolog this will look like:

```
sameSeqDiffs([X, Y], D) :-
    ___.
```

(with the `___` to be filled in).

Now for the inductive case we can define a `sameSeqDiffs/2` in terms of itself, although *not* with the same parameters of course. In mathematics, one sometimes defines a function *f* such that for example *f(i) = 2×f(i-1)*; with for example *f(0) = 1* as base. We can in a similar way define an inductive case for `sameSeqDiffs/2`:

> *(inductive case)* For a list of more than two elements, all elements in the list have the same difference, given the first two elements have a difference `D`, and in the list of elements except the first element, all elements have that difference `D` as well.

In Prolog this will look like:

```
sameSeqDiffs([X, Y, Z|T], D) :-
    ___,
    sameSeqDiffs(___, ___).
```

## Arithmetic in Prolog

A common mistake people who start programming in Prolog make is they think that, like it is common in many programming languages, Prolog add semantics to certain functors.

For example one can think that `A - 1` will decrement `A`. For Prolog this is however just `-(A, 1)`, it is not minus, or anything else, just a functor. As a result Prolog will *not* evaluate such expressions. So if you write `X = A - 1`, then `X` is just `X = -(A,1)`.

Then how can we perform numerical operations? Prolog systems have a predicate `is/2`, that evaluates the right hand side by attaching semantics to the right hand side. So the `is/2` predicate will *interpret* this `(+)/2`, `(-)/2`, etc. functors (`(+)/2` as plus, `(-)/2` as minus, etc.).

So we can evaluate an expression like:

```
A = 4, is(X, A - 1).
```

and then `X` will be set to `3`, *not* `4-1`. Prolog also allows to write the `is` infix, like:

```
A = 4, X is A - 1.
```

Here you will need this to *calculate* the difference between two elements.

Comment: Thank you so much for this concise tutorial on my problem!! This was a ton of help to me and I think I understand what I am doing for this problem now. Cheers friend!

Answer (score 0):

You were very close with your second attempt. It should have been

```erlang
samediffs( [X,  Y | Rest], Result):-
    Result is Y - X,
    samediffs( [Y | Rest], Result).
```

And you don't even need "to split the first two elements from the list". This will take care of itself.

How? Simple: calling `samediffs( List, D)`, on the first entry into the predicate, the *not yet instantiated* `D = Result`  will be instantiated to the calculated difference between the second and the first element in the list by the call `Result is Y - X`.

On each subsequent entry into the predicate, which is to say, for each subsequent *pair* of elements `X`, `Y` in the list, the call `Result is Y - X` will calculate the difference for *that* pair, and will check the numerical equality for it and `Result` which at this point holds the previously calculated value.

In case they aren't equal, the predicate will fail.

In case they are, the recursion will continue.

The only thing missing is the base case for this recursion:

```erlang
samediffs( [_], _Result).  
samediffs( [], _Result).
```

In case it was a singleton (or even empty) list all along, this will leave the differences argument `_Result` uninstantiated. It can be interpreted as a checking predicate, in such a case. There's certainly no unequal differences between elements in a singleton (or even more so, empty) list.

---

In general, ......

```erlang
recursion(A, B):- base_case( A, B).

recursion(  Thing,  NewThing):-
  combined( Thing,             Shell, Core),
  recursion(                          Core, NewCore),
  combined(         NewThing,  Shell,       NewCore).
```

*...... Recursion!*