# Output seems to only test the very last in the list for difference function

Tags: list, recursion, prolog

Link to old question: [Checking if the difference between consecutive elements is the same](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52555706/checking-if-the-difference-between-consecutive-elements-is-the-same)

I have posted my progress in another question post, but here is my code my the problem I am trying to solve in Prolog. I would like my function to return the result of sameSeqDiffs([3,5,7],2) depending on whether the difference between each number is the same as my last argument. Here is what I cam up with so far:

```
sameSeqDiffs([X,Y], Result):-
    A is Y - X,
    A = Result.

sameSeqDiffs([X,Y,Z|T], Result):-
    sameSeqDiffs([Y,Z|T], Result).
```

When I test this code, it seems to work for some input, but clearly fails for others:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your solution has some issues:

```
sameSeqDiffs([X,Y,Z|T], Result):-
    sameSeqDiffs([Y,Z|T], Result).
```

Here you ignore completely variable X and the difference X-Y.

```
sameSeqDiffs([X,Y], Result):-
    Result is Y - X.

sameSeqDiffs([X,Y,Z|T], Result):-
    Result is Y - X,
    sameSeqDiffs([Y,Z|T], Result).
```

Answer (score 1):

In essence you forgot one thing: to calculate the difference in the *recursive* case:

```
sameSeqDiffs([X,Y], Result):-
    A is Y - X,
    A = Result.

sameSeqDiffs([X,Y,Z|T], Result):-
    Result is Y - X,
    sameSeqDiffs([Y,Z|T], Result).
```

So here we unify `Result` with the difference between `Y` and `X`. We make a recurive call with this difference, such that a "deeper" recursive call will unify against the already grounded difference. If the differences do not match, then the predicate will fail.

You can also make the first clause a bit more elegant, by immediately using `Result` in the `is/2` predicate call, instead of first using a variable (`A`), and then unifying it, so:

```
sameSeqDiffs([X,Y], Result):-
    Result is Y - X.

sameSeqDiffs([X,Y,Z|T], Result):-
    Result is Y - X,
    sameSeqDiffs([Y,Z|T], Result).
```

We then obtain the following results:

```
?- sameSeqDiffs([3, 5, 7], D).
D = 2 ;
false.

?- sameSeqDiffs([3, 5, 7], 2).
true ;
false.

?- sameSeqDiffs([3, 5, 7], 4).
false.

?- sameSeqDiffs([2, 3, 4], 1).
true ;
false.

?- sameSeqDiffs([2, 3, 4, 6], 2).
false.

?- sameSeqDiffs([2, 3, 4, 6], 1).
false.
```

The fact that it returns `false` after a `true` is due to Prolog backtracing and aiming to find another solution. So if it prints `true; false.` we know that an attempt was successful, and hence the predicate succeeded.

Answer (score 0):

For problems like this it's a good time to learn about CLP(FD) which is the part of Prolog used to reason over integers:

```
same_seq_dif([X,Y], R) :- Y - X #= R.
same_seq_dif([X,Y,Z|T], R) :-
    Y - X #= R,
    same_seq_dif([Y,Z|T], R).
```

In addition to yielding correct results when you provide a fully instantiated list, it knows how to handle more general cases as well:

```
| ?- same_seq_dif([X,5,7], R).

R = 2
X = 3 ? ;

no
| ?- length(L,3), same_seq_dif(L, 3), fd_labeling(L).

L = [0,3,6] ? ;

L = [1,4,7] ? ;

L = [2,5,8] ? ;

L = [3,6,9] ? ;

L = [4,7,10] ?
...
```

I'm using GNU Prolog, thus the `fd_labeling/1` predicate. SWI has a similar predicate, `label/1`.