# prolog pattern identification for list of numbers

Tags: prolog, pattern-matching

So I'm trying to identify if a list of numbers can be identified as a arithmetic progression. For example I have a list of numbers `[5, 10, 15, 20]` I need to make predicates that will identify this as arithmetic progression.

Comment: Nice arithmetic progression :) What is your question?

Comment: Well I'm trying to figure out how to compare each number in the list. Or at least a way to go about this?

Comment: start with "designing" an inductive definition: when is a list of zero, one, two, n+1 elements in arithmetic progression?

Comment: A list can be written as `[X, Y|T]` where `X` and `Y `are the first two elements and T is the tail. You can compare `X` and `Y`. You can then do a recursive call on `[Y|T]` and then look at that list as `[A,B|T]` and follow that pattern until the end of the list. You can start the whole process by looking at the difference between the first two elements, then recursively ensure that the rest of the list matches.

Comment: Ok I'm starting to understand it but one other issue I have is that some of the lists are different lengths.

Comment: @Daniel: that is where the recursive part comes in: if you manage to define the predicate for lists "larger than two elements" in terms of "the list without one element", by induction you defined it over lists of any length larger than two.

Comment: Ok this making a lot of sense.

Comment: It doesn't matter how long the list is. `[X|T]` represents a list whose first element is `X` and `T` is a list which represents "the rest of the list". So it's arbitrary. That's how list processing works in Prolog: you examine `X` for a list `[X|T]` then recursively examine list `T`. In this case, you care about the front two elements, so you examine `[X, Y|T]`. At a Prolog prompt, try this unification and see what Prolog tells you: `[1,2,3,4,5] = [X|T]`. Also try, `[1,2,3,4,5] = [X,Y|T]`. Prolog will perform these unifications by instantiating `X`, `Y`, and `T` appropriately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can find out the difference between two separate numbers just fine:

```erlang
diff_between( A, B, C):- 
    C is A - B.
```

As for the lists, we need to pair up the consecutive elements

```erlang
pairs( G3, [A | B], C):-   % G3 is a goal expecting of 3 arguments
    append( D, [_], [A | B]),
    maplist( call(G3), B, D, C).
```

Now we can get the list of differences between the consecutive elements:

```erlang
consec_diffs( L, Diffs):-
    pairs( diff_between, L, Diffs).
 %  pairs( G3,         [A | B], C)
 %  maplist( call(diff_between), B, D, Diffs )

% consec_diffs( [a,b,c, ..., n,m], Diffs)
% =
%              [ b,c, ..., n,m ]
%              [ a,b, ....., n ]
%             ------------------- pairwise diff_between
%      Diffs = [ ............. ]
```

And then we just need to find out whether all of them are the same:

```erlang
is_arith_prog( A ):-
    consec_diffs( A, [B | C]),
    maplist( =:=(B), C).
```

This answer mainly just has a curiosity value. It does too much work potentially. The proper way to code anything is while doing as little work as possible and reaching the conclusion as soon as possible. In this case it is done by a straightforward recursive definition processing the list in the top-down manner.

Comment: I am vary new to prolog and I am just confused on what call(G3) does?

Comment: @Daniel My answer is a bit on the advanced side of things. You should come to it *after* you've mastered the stuff in the answer by lurker (or in [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52570770/849891)), i.e. *after* it is easy for you to code the straight-up recursive definitions yourself, by hand. --- `call( diff_between, 3, 2, X)` will call `diff_between(3, 2, X)` which will instantiate `X` as `1`. `call(diff_between)` will be *applied* by `maplist/4` to each corresponding set of elements from its argument lists, one by one, filling in the missing arguments in the call to `diff_between/3`.

Comment: `pairs( G3, ...)` accepts any predicate specification of your choosing to call with the subsequent pairs of elements. `G3` is a logical variable, named so in order to evoke "goal" and "3", for *a goal which expects three arguments*. This is self-evident to a more seasoned Prolog coder;  while you're not there yet it is beneficial to add such verbose explanations in the comments.

Answer (score 2):

I'll try to give you a framework without giving away the whole answer. The bottom line is that you should go online or get a text book and study Prolog recursive list processing.

```
arith_prog([X,Y|T]) :-
    Diff #= X - Y,
    arith_prog([Y|T], Diff).

arith_prog([_], _). % A single element list is a degenerate arith prog
arith_prog([X,Y|T], Diff) :- ... (what goes here?)
```

Note that I'm using CLP(FD) here (thus, the `#=/2` operator). That's the best way of reasoning with integers in Prolog and provides the most general solution. If you want to limit this to checking fully instantiated numeric lists, then you could use `Diff is X - Y`.